# Link_to delete button from a class: can't convert String into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this simple Ruby class (I use it from within a controller to create a collection of products):

```
class ProductDashboardDecorator
    include ApplicationHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    include ActionController::UrlWriter

    def initialize(p)
        @product = p
    end

    def special_links
        ret = ''
         # this works!
         ret << content_tag(:a, 'X', :href => removee_product_path(@product), :title => 'rimuovi', :class => 'remove_link', :method => :delete)

         # this don't!
         ret << link_to('X', removee_product_path(@product), :title => 'rimuovi', :class => 'remove_link', :method => :delete)

        return ret.html_safe
    end
end
```

I want to use link_to to create a "delete" button. But when I do, I get this error:

```
can't convert String into Hash
```

These are the routes:

```
map.resources :products, :member => { :removee => :delete }, :as => 'prodotti' do |product|
    product.resources :watchers, :collection => { :add => :get }
  end
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax, Not tested

```
content_tag(:span, link_to('X', removee_product_path(@product), :title => 'rimuovi', :class => 'remove_link', :method => :delete))
```

Comment: the problem is always generated by this: link_to('X', removee_product_path(@product)). Same error